# Listing all elements of a vector

Tags: c#

I don't understand what I've doen wrong. This is a project where there is a bus and the user is supposed to be able to add a passenger (maximum 25 ppl) with an age, be shown all the different ages and be shown the total age of all the passengers. I think the main problem is in the method for showing all the different ages. When I run the program only the last entered age and then 24 zeros are shown when calling for this method. Otherwise there is no problem. I insert the whole project, maybe there's and issue with something else...

```
using System;

namespace Bussen
{
    class Buss
    {
        public int[] passagerare = new int[25];



        public void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the awesome Buss-simulator");

            //variabel
            int input = 0;

            //meny i do-while loop
            do
            {
                //alternativ i menyn
                Console.WriteLine("Tryck [1] för att lägga till en passagerare. ");
                Console.WriteLine("Tryck [2] för att visa passagerarnas olika åldrar. ");
                Console.WriteLine("Tryck [3] för att räkna ut den totala ålderna av alla passagerare. ");
                Console.WriteLine("Tryck [0] för att avsluta programmet.");

                try
                {
                    input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }

                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Skriv endast in ett nummer från menyn, tack.");
                }

                // meny med 4 val
                switch (input)
                {
                    case 1:
                        add_passenger();
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till en passagerare.");
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Console.Clear();
                        print_buss();
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        int age = calc_total_age();
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Den totala åldern av passagerarna är {0}. ", age);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        break;

                }
            } while (input != 0);


        }



        public void add_passenger()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < passagerare.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Lägg till en passagerare genom att ange åldern ");
                int age;


                //try catch, om användaren skriver in något annat än en int bes den att skriva om
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Skriv endast in heltal");
                        
                    }
                    
                }

                //age som användaren valt lagars i vektor
                passagerare[i] = age;
                break;
            }
        }

        public void print_buss()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("De som sitter i bussen är följande år gamla ");
            for(int i = 0;i < passagerare.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(passagerare[i]);
            }
            
            

        }

        public int calc_total_age()
        {
            int age1 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < passagerare.Length; i++)
            {
                if (passagerare[i] == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                age1 += passagerare[i];
            }
            return age1;
        }




    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var minbuss = new Buss();
            minbuss.Run();
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking here

```
//age som användaren valt lagars i vektor
                passagerare[i] = age;
                break; //remove this
```

You are breaking after taking the first input.
There are many more problems in your code which I suggest to consult with your teacher(seems like this is homework), anyway here are few

```
                if (passagerare[i] == null)
```

This will never be null, default value of int is '0', and even if the value is zero. age + 0 = age so there is no harm adding it.

```
                    
                        age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Instead of try catch, use [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0) then break.